# Create a postgres trigger on new row with specific value in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a table, `replies` and I would like to update a specific row in `posts` when `replies` has a new row inserted with a foreign key from `posts`.

Here is what I've got so far:

```sql
-- Inserts a row into public.users
create or replace function public.handle_updated_at() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
  update posts set updated_at = now() where postid = (postid) 
  -- not sure what goes here ^, postid comes from public.replies as a foreign key of posts

  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

-- Trigger the function every time a user is created
create trigger on_new_reply
  after insert on public.replies
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_updated_at();
```

I'm not sure what the correct approach to this is as I haven't had much experience with SQL related things and I find the Postgres documentation to be quite difficult to understand.

My question remains, what should my trigger/function/both look like in order for this work as proposed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted you table definitions so I will assume that `postid` is unique (or PK)  `posts` table and a FK in `replies`. As your function currently stands it updates *every row* in the `posts` table. The extra parenthesis in the where clause mean nothing to Postgres. So `where postid = (postid)` is exactly the same as `where postid = postid`. Which is true for every row in the table or the same as no where clause. To get just the postid row being updated you reference `new.postid`. So your trigger function becomes:

```
-- Inserts a row into public.users
create or replace function public.handle_updated_at() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
  update posts 
     set updated_at = now() 
   where postid = new.postid;
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

Your trigger itself is fine.